# ¿Como escojer un especifico ID de un foreach?

Tags: php, sql

mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $resultado = conexion($sql);
        $data["titulo"] = "Result";
        $data["Result"] = $resultado;
        
        foreach($data["Result"] as $dato){
        $id = $dato["id"];
        $nombre = $dato["nombre"];

echo $id;
echo $nombre;
        }
    ?>
```

Dentro de la tabla a la que esta haciendo referencia el `$sql` tengo solamente 3 usuarios y por consecuencia 3 ID, lo que quiero lograr es que me pueda imprimir solamente el ID 2 del ciclo que se esta haciendo, he intentado de esta forma:

```
    <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
                $resultado = conexion($sql);
                $data["titulo"] = "Result";
                $data["Result"] = $resultado;
                
                foreach($data["Result"] as $dato){
                $id = $dato["id"];
                $nombre = $dato["nombre"];
        }
        echo $id;
        echo $nombre;
?>
```

Con esto simplemente consigo que me imprima el ultimo ID y el ultimo nombre, pero sinceramente no tengo la minima idea de como poder conseguir que solo me imprima el ID 2, ¿Alguno de ustedes me puede ayudar con esto? Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con añadir un `if($dato["id"]==2)` en tu `foreach` debería funcionar. Algo así:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $resultado = conexion($sql);
    $data["titulo"] = "Result";
    $data["Result"] = $resultado;

    foreach($data["Result"] as $dato){
        if($dato["id"]==2){
            $id = $dato["id"];
            $nombre = $dato["nombre"];
        }
    }
    echo $id;
    echo $nombre;
?>
```